# Ignoring a specific file in a shell script for loop

Tags: python, shell, for-loop, yaml

My shell script loops through a given directory to execute a python script. I want to be able to ignore a specific file which is export_config.yaml. This is currently used in the for loop and prints out error on the terminal I want it to totally ignore this file.

```
yamldir=$1


for yaml in ${yamldir}/*.yaml; do

if [ "$yaml" != "export_config.yaml" ]; then

    echo "Running export for $yaml file...";
    python jsonvalid.py -p ${yamldir}/export_config.yaml -e $yaml -d ${endDate}
    wait

fi
```

done

Comment: Please provide us with the error trace so we can help you faster.

Comment: Just provided with the error trace @kamses

Comment: Okay cool. Based on the trace, it looks like the error is in your python file, not the shell script. Thus, we'll have to see the contents of `jsonvalid.py` to determine the issue. As you can see from the trace, the offending code is on line 23 in your `main()` function.

Comment: Added python code @kamses

Comment: Yeah, you're right. One of the options in my answer below should fix your issue and successfully skip `export_config.yaml`

Comment: (Please leave posts in a state useful for others (or delete them altogether *if you think stackoverflow will be better without them*).)

Comment: Yes I will make sure to remember that for the next time I post a quesiton @greybeard

Comment: (It's just that I'm not sure whether it is more useful *with* the parts added and then removed again or without them. (BTW: what *does* the `done` stand for?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string comparison in the `if` statement is not matching `export_config.yaml` because for each iteration of your `for` loop you are assigning the entire relative file path (ie "`$yamldir/export_config.yaml`", not just "`export_config.yaml`") to `$yaml`.

**First Option:** Changing your `if` statement to reflect that should correct your issue:

```
if [ "$yaml" != "${yamldir}/export_config.yaml" ]; then
#etc...
```

**Another option:** Use `basename` to grab only the terminal path string (ie the filename).

```
for yaml in ${yamldir}/*.yaml; do
yaml=$(basename $yaml)
if [ "$yaml" != "export_config.yaml" ]; then
#etc...
```

**Third option:** You can do away with the `if` statement entirely by doing your `for` loop like this instead:

`for yaml in $(ls ${yamldir}/*.yaml | grep -v "export_config.yaml"); do`

By piping the output of `ls` to `grep -v`, you can exclude any line including `export_config.yaml` from the directory listing in the first place.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. The grep command works a charm and easy to explain. Thanks @kamses